# Error while running a large BigQuery code in R

Tags: r, google-bigquery, bigrquery

I am running my BigQuery code in RStudio using `bigrquery` package and one of the lines of the query contains a large list of integers (approx. 500 numbers).
The query runs perfectly on BigQuery but when I try to run the same in RStudio using the above said package, it throws me the following error:

```
Syntax error: Expected ")" or "," but got keyword GROUP at [180:1] [invalidQuery]
```

I believe the problem is due to the large list that I have written in the query because when I print my results without that list and filter out later using `R`, it works perfectly but the only problem then is that I have to download large quantity of results (approx. 1.6M rows) which takes a lot of time.

Does anyone know a work around such problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Probably (what else could it be?) you've got a missing closing bracket `)` before the GROUP keyword, as the error message informs you. What happens if you add this to the query?

Comment: 'The query runs perfectly on BigQuery'. Already stated.

Comment: R != BigQuery. While BigQuery may ignore syntax errors, R certainly won't.

Comment: Sorry but I'm unable to make sense out of what you're saying. First, why would BigQuery ignore errors? It doesn't. It definitely gives a warning message when there is a wrong syntax. Second, the problem here is that the query that runs perfectly in BigQuery is throwing a syntax error when run in RStudio using `bigrquery`

Comment: I dont know. Ive never used BigQuery. But maybe you've just answered your own question. Google's BigQuery gives a warning if the query has syntax errors, but still runs, as long as the errors are not too stupid. R will definitely not run if the query has syntax errors. Your query has a syntax error. Solution: correct it.